# In Kedro, how to pick up intermediate dataset in a pipeline?

Tags: kedro

I'm working on my pipeline and testing it manually on jupyter notebook.

Here is my situation.

I wanted to pick up `example_train` and `example_valid` from it,  so I wrote like this.

`context.pipeline.to_outputs("example_train", "example_valid")`

and passed this another pipeline into SequencialRunner, and I got them.

[image: example of pipeline]

And I also wanted `total_steps` so I changed the line like this.

`context.pipeline.to_outputs("example_train", "example_valid", "total_steps")`

but, the result did not contain `exampe_train`.
Yes, I understood `example_train` wasn't the output of this modified pipeline, so it didn't contain.

[image]

Is there a way to pick up an intermediate dataset like this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can define each of these datasets in the data catalog in `catalog.yml` and define where they should be stored.

So for example:

```
example_train:
  type: pandas.CSVDataSet
  filepath: data/02_intermediate/example_train.csv
```

For more information on how to use the DataCatalog see: https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/05_data/01_data_catalog.html#using-the-data-catalog-within-kedro-configuration

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it's not worth for debugging. my purpose is not save the intermediate dataset but access these intermediate objects via jupyter notebook.